# lightning-icon is not working on the model window

Tags: lightning-web-components, slds, lightning-combobox

The code below is a model window, and I am want utility: forward icon to display in the middle of combobox and the button but nothing displays. And for the combobox, the inverted triangle is also not displayed. when I inspect in the browser, I can see the icon(code) but not in UI. Any inputs please

```
    <template>
   <div class="main-container" >
    <section  data-id="zmtModal" role="dialog" tabindex="-1"  aria-modal="true" aria-describedby="modal-content-id-1" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open">
        <div class="slds-modal__container" >
           
            <header class="slds-modal__header" style=" background-color:#FAFAFA; border-bottom-width: 0px;">
                <h2 id="modal-heading-01" class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-hyphenate"><strong>Assign Market</strong></h2>
            </header>
            <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium" id="modal-content-id-1" style=" background-color: #FAFAFA">
                <div style="padding-bottom: 30px;">
                    <p class="para1Style">The following some text which is not important </p>
                   
               </div> 
            
                <div style="background-color:#FFFEFF;width:614px; height: 64px; padding-left: 0px;border-radius:6px; margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto; margin-bottom: 20px;">
                    <div style="padding:20px; ">
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="width: 120px;">&nbsp; &nbsp; Quick Assign: &nbsp;</td>
                                <td><div style="width:206px; padding-bottom: 15px; height:33px; ">
                                        <lightning-combobox
                                                    class="comboQAStyle"
                                                    name="label"
                                                    label="select"
                                                    value={assignValue}
                                                    variant="label-hidden"
                                                    placeholder="Select"
                                                    options={LstOfOptions}
                                                    onchange={handleChange} 
                                                    disabled={disableCombo}></lightning-combobox>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:forward" size="small"></lightning-icon>
                                </td>
                                <td>&nbsp; &nbsp;Assign to:&nbsp;</td>
                                <td><lightning-button variant="brand-outline" label="Select" onclick={handleBtn} class="slds-m-left_x-small" disabled={disableButton}></lightning-button></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
 </section> 
</div>
</template>
```